# Lost bearing on disc brake for Kona Jake The Snake 2016

Tags: disc-brake, bearings

I have [this bike](https://2016.konaworld.com/jake_the_snake.cfm), and I appear to have [lost the bearing on the front wheel](https://photos.app.goo.gl/5cGtXhuL7sQgYAGq9), causing the disc brake to rub up against the fork when I'm riding. (I'm not a bike expert, so sorry if I'm using the wrong terms.)

I was going to donate this bike, but now I don't want to give up so easily, it's a good bike and I like it a lot. Is there a part that I can buy that would fix this issue? Something from [here](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=bike+wheel+bearing&ref=nb_sb_noss_2) for example?

[image: Image linked by OP, inlined for convenience and prevent link rot.]

Comment: Or do I need to replace the axle? http://konaparts.com/product/kona-frame-thru-axle-cmpaxr03/ or http://konaparts.com/product/kona-qr-thru-axle-142x12mm/ for example.

Answer (score 2):

You have not lost the bearing. Bearings are pressed into hubs and don't come out easily. What you see in the middle of the brake rotor is the bearing - you can see the black plastic dust seal. What has gone missing is the hub end cap. Many wheels have replaceable end caps that allow conversion between through axle and quick release forks or frames.

Finding a replacement end cap might be difficult. The web page you linked to says the hubs are Novatech. Try contacting their [customer support](https://www.novatecusa.net/contact/) and asking of they can supply an replacement part.